# Use lower compatibility in .net application for incompatible .net framework 4.6.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

I am currently using my .net application with `.Net framework 4.6.1` .On upgrading the framework to `4.6.2`, my exception logging code becomes incompatible.

How do I run my currently deployed applications **incompatible** with 4.6.2 on servers with framework 4.6.2? Modifying the code for the previously deployed applications is not feasible as those are client production sites.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "my exception logging code becomes incompatible"? I would strongly expect updating from 4.6.1 to 4.6.2 to be fine. Please give more details - it'll be really, *really* hard to help you without that extra information.

Comment: @JonSkeet My code refers to dlls from the ExceptionManagementApplicationBlock to write any exceptions raised by the application to the EventVwr. Now these dlls are not compatible with framework 4.6.2. For framework 4.6.2 i am using Log4net which works fine.The servers need to be updated to 4.6.2. How do i get the previously deployed application to work on these servers?

Comment: Again, in what way is it not compatible? Provide details in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I haven't been able to figure out exactly how it is incompatible. All i know is that the w3wp worker process crashes because of this which causes the app pool to stop

Comment: Well you should come up with a minimal example to demonstrate that, and tell us everything you've done to diagnose the problem.